# Unit Test MongoDB query using Mongoose Promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, tdd, mocha.js

I am working on a complex calculation which involves collecting data from multiple collections and then crunching the numbers. To that end, I am following TDD and want to write a Unit Test first. I understand querying a database violates the unit test paradigm and I should use mock objects but I for the time being I want to query the database to test a few numbers out. I'm trying to use Mongoose promises to get around the asynchronous aspect of NodeJS but I am not able to figure it out. Here's my code:

```
(function (argument) {
'use strict';

var should = require('should');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MeasureTherm = mongoose.model('MeasureTherm');

describe('Calculations Server Test', function (){

    describe('Model Tests', function () {
        it('should find all MeasureTherms for a Program, Year and End Use', function () {
            var promise = getMeasureThermsByProgramAndEndUse("Program 1", 2015, "End Use 1").then(function(results) {
                this.fulfill(results);
            });

            promise.onFulfill(function(results){
                assert.equal(200, results.length);
            });

        });
    });
});

var getMeasureThermsByProgramAndEndUse = function (program, year, endUse) {
     return MeasureTherm.find().exec();
};
})();
```

My test always passes even if I enter invalid number in my assert.equal().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in done as the function parameter of the test.  This will tell the unit test not to end until it is called.

```
it('should find all MeasureTherms for a Program, Year and End Use', function (done) { //<-- HERE
        var promise = getMeasureThermsByProgramAndEndUse("Program 1", 2015, "End Use 1").then(function(results) {
            this.fulfill(results);
        });

        promise.onFulfill(function(results){
            assert.equal(200, results.length);
            done(); //<-- AND HERE
        });

    });
```